# Correctly configure NGINX to redirect http and all vhosts to specific address

Tags: nginx, configuration, redirect

I am unfamiliar with setting up the config and I feel that I've got most of my config right, but there is specific functionality that I can't configure correctly.

#### What I'm trying to accomplish:

1. All http(80) traffic redirect to https(443) automatically
2. I want the server block to work as a "catch-all"

   - Also working as a "catch-all" I want **any** (http and https) requests for www.example.com, example.com, bob.example.com, -randomstring-.example.com to redirect to site.example.com so that it will read `https://site.example.com` in the address bar.

.

#### What is already working:

1. http redirect to https (ssl cert config works fine)
2. `http://-randomstring-.example.com` ***will*** redirect `https://site.example.com` like I want it to.

#### What is **NOT** working:

1. requests for `https://-randomstring-.example.com` will remain rather than redirecting to `https://site.example.com`

#### Also there are some things to note:

1. The public DNS wildcard *.example.com resolves to my servers IP
2. This is main config: http://pastebin.com/rqzQDwyD
3. This is the included config: http://pastebin.com/D87R6LJK

Does anyone understand how I want it to work, and is it possible with NGINX??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by Martin was only partially working. It would throw the browser into an infinite redirect loop, which is bad. I did some searching and here is a working config for what i need. here is a full config: http://pastebin.com/ngPUH5P2

and here is just the partial config that i needed (i dont want to post the whole massively irrelevant config)

```
    if ($host !~* ^site\.) {  
    return 301 https://site.example.com$request_uri$is_args$args;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a server block for *example.com accessed via ssl should be enough provided your ssl certificate is a wildcard certificate.

```
server {
    listen                  443 ssl;

    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/cert/_.example.com-chained.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/cert/_.example.com.key.insecure;
    ssl_session_timeout     15m;
    ssl_protocols           SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers             ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    server_name             *.example.com;

    return 301 https://site.example.com$request_uri$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: I have tried as you suggested and i get this error in various browsers: http://i.imgur.com/J9B1Onx.png

seems like a redirect loop, is there a way to break the loop?